# Receiving Data on the servlet From Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, http, servlets, http-post

I am trying to send data to from my android app to the servlet using POST method but servlet don't show any kind of the activity just null has shown in the output. Although I am receiving response from servlet on the android app using GET method. 
We try to print action on logcat. It shows that data has been sent but show null on browser.
I am also receiving  exception "Invalid use of single client connection manager:Connection still allocated"

Android Code:-

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8084/AndroidApp/AndroidServlet";

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

try {

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Father", father));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Gender", gender));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, res);
}
```

Servlet Code:-

```
public class AndroidServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String Name=request.getParameter("Name");
    String Father=request.getParameter("Father");
    String Gender=request.getParameter("Gender");

     try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("Hello Android !!!!");
        out.println( Name  + " " +  Father + " "  +  Gender + " ");

    }
}
```

Output on Browser:-

```
Hello Android !!!!
null null null
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to debug net apps without external tools and of course it will be difficult to find bug in your code without compiling it.
For debugging such apps I use Android Emulator + WireShark to look at the body of HTTP request. Hope it'll help.

Edited:

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try{
            String strResponseSaveGoal =
                    httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("sendCancelOrderRequest", strResponseSaveGoal);
        }catch ( ConnectTimeoutException conEx )
        {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(CANCEL_REQUEST_ERROR);
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
            Log.d("sendCancelOrderRequest","");
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(CANCEL_REQUEST_ERROR);
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("sendCancelOrderRequest","");
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(CANCEL_REQUEST_ERROR);
        }
```

Comment: Well can you tell if there is any problem in my method or the method is correct and problem is elsewhere

Comment: I'm not Nastradamus ) I can't debug code in my brains) Actually I don't see any bug in your code. But I should recomend you to catch other exception. Look at my modified answer above

Comment: Set up wireshark. This is the best way to find bug. I can't help you cause I have no Web server to install server side of your application.